# In theory, how fast could I possibly serve in a game of ping-pong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics, biology

A tennis player can serve in a more or less straight line from their racket to the service box on the other side of the net: there's a direct line of sight. That means that there's no inherent limit on how fast they can serve.

On the other hand a ping-pong player cannot take advantage of this straight line - their serve must bounce on their own side of the table, pass over the net, and then descend in time to touch the opposing side. A ping-pong serve cannot exceed a certain velocity, otherwise the ball will land beyond the table.

What is the maximum velocity at which a ping-pong ball can be served?

If the height of a ping-pong net is 15.25 cm and gravity accelerates falling objects at 9.8 metres per second per second, then in a vacuum, the ball takes sqrt(2 * .1525/9.8) = 0.1764155576 seconds to reach the table from the height of the net.

Each half of the table is 137 cm long, so if you hit the ball straight over the net, it cannot exceed a speed of 1.37 m / 0.1764155576 seconds, or 7.7657550084 metres per second.

But, you can serve diagonally from one corner to the other, and the diagonal is ~1.525 metres, so if you stand in the right place, hit the ball so that bounces off the table at ~5.7 degrees from the horizontal plane, your fastest possible serve - when playing in a vacuum - is 8.6443623269 metres/second.

However very few people get to play ping-pong in a vacuum, so we ought to take account of wind resistance, which will slow down the ball as it travels.

The ball has a mass of 2.7 mm, and a diameter of 40 mm, and I suppose it has some coefficient of friction or drag in air. How should we calculate the fastest possible service speed now?

What's more, we can hit the ball with spin, which substantially changes its behaviour in the air. Can that be modelled?

In short: in theory, how fast could I possibly serve in a game of ping-pong?

Comment: Re, "ball with spin...can that be modelled?" Google for "Magnus effect."

Comment: Obligatory XKCD and Veritasium video. [Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/), [Backspin Basketball Flies Off Dam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OSrvzNW9FE)